# Why does vim/neovim keep creating files named `<n>:p` in my current working directory?

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin

I keep ending up with a bunch of files named `<number>:p` in my working directory, and I'm struggling to find any meaningful results on Google about this.

I think it might be related to asynchronous tasks running on a file when I save it and quit at the same time (possibly ALE plugin?).

Does anybody know how to fix this? It's getting a bit tedious having to run `rm *:p` often.

Here is an example `git status` output showing what I mean:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    10:p
    12:p
    19:p
    20:p
    47:p
    60:p
```

I've tried searching Google, and also searching my nvim config folder for `:p`, but since `:p` is a vim command I'm struggling to find anything helpful.

Comment: Could you kindly provide a minimal reproducible `.vimrc` or `init.vim`? Otherwise, we can't say what's going on.

Comment: OK, I thought it might be a common issue but just difficult to search Google for! I will try disabling plugins etc and diagnose, and report back with either an answer myself if I can reach one, or more information if not. Thanks!

Comment: This looks a lot like a failed attempt to use `:help filename-modifiers` in order to obtain a full path.